# New line error for Redcarpet gem

Tags: ruby, markdown, rspec-rails, redcarpet, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a `#markdown` method in my `ApplicationHelper` that I wanted write a simple unit test:

```
def markdown(text)
  markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML)
  markdown.render(text).html_safe # tried wihout html_safe too
end
```

Whenever I wrote a RSpec test, it kept failing. I tried it with three different ways:

```
expect(helper.markdown('# Header')).to eq('<h1>Header</h1>')
# => expected: "<h1>Header</h1>" but got: "<h1>Header</h1>\n"

expect(helper.markdown('# Header')).to eq('<h1>Header</h1>\n')
# => expected: "<h1>Header</h1>\\n" got: "<h1>Header</h1>\n"

expect(helper.markdown('# Header').delete_suffix('\n')).to eq('<h1>Header</h1>')
# => expected: "<h1>Header</h1>" got: "<h1>Header</h1>\n"
```

How can I make this unit test pass?

> Ruby 2.5.1 | Rspec 3.7.0 | Rails 5.2 | Redcarpet 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence `\n` is only parsed as an escape code for a newline when it is between double quotes: `"\n"`. In single quotes it is just a literal `\` and a literal `n`.

To get the test to pass you just need to use double quotes in the string with the `\n`:

```
expect(helper.markdown('# Header')).to eq("<h1>Header</h1>\n")
```